# Select categories from table 1 and products from table2?

Tags: asp.net, sql, select

I need to display some lists of products.
I have 2 tables, one with the `categories` and one with all the `products`.

And I need to display this structure:

```
list 1.
write - categories_id from categories table
write - list of products with the above categories_id from products table
end of list

next list2.
write - next categories_id from categories table
write - list of products with the above list2 categories_id from products table
end of list
```

and so on...

So I need to select all the categories_id from categories and all the matching categories_ids from the products table.

What is the best way of doing this?
Should I select all from `categories` and then inside the do until... select all products...or?

Lets say that there is 4 categories in the categories table, so it should display 4 lists with 10 products in each list.
The sql that I have looks like this:

```
sql3 = "SELECT * from categories c inner join products p on c.categories_id = p.categories_id where p.userid ='1' group by c.categories_id order by c.categories_id;"

and the do until looks like:
do until rs.eof
rs("categoriName")

rs("productsName")

rs.movenext
loop
```

But this generates 4 lists with just 1 product in each?

Ok, my tables looks like this:

```
categories table:
categories_id, userId, categoriesName

products table:
products_id, user_id, categories_id, productsName


And the do:
<% do until rs.eof %>
Categori: <%=rs("categoriesName")%>

Product:<%=rs("productsName")%>
<% rs.movenext
loop %>
```

And the lists should look like this:

```
(list 1)
Categori: Phones
Product: iPhone
Product: Samsung
Product: Nokia

(list 2)

Categori: Tvs
Product: Philips
Product: Sony
Product: Sharp
```

Maybe Im just thinking wrong trying to do this in one select, maybe I just need two selects, the first that selects the categories name and loop through that and inside that loop, select the products.?

Comment: This is basic SQL. Is better to get and read a book about because you can not make a full program by making questions on every sql query that you can not handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that will fetch all the categories with their corresponding products:

```
SELECT
    c.CategoryName, P.ProductName, p.Price, ... //What data you want to select
FROM
    CategoriesList c
INNER JOIN 
    Products p ON c.Id = p. CategoryId
ORDER BY 
    c.CategoryName, p.ProductName
```

This is the best way you should use to get your data. Then you can output these results the way you want in you application that will consume this query, for example, in your case you should print the first `categoryname` as a title then its `products` list as subitems and so on.

**Update:** For example this how you can output them in a console application:

```
foreach( var category in categoriesList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("(List {0})", category.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Category: {0}", category.Name);
    foreach(var product in category.Products)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}", product.Name); 
    }
}
```

This should print:

```
(list 1)
Category: Phones
Product: iPhone
Product: Samsung
Product: Nokia
(list 2)
Category: Tvs
Product: Philips
Product: Sony
Product: Sharp
...
```

Note that: the data coming form the database is a tabular data in the form:

```
 CategoryId  | CategoryName  |  ProductName |
-------------+---------------+--------------+
      1           Phones          iPhone
      1           Phones          Samsung  
     ...
```

And here the database role is over, because the db isn't about how to represent your data, or how your data would look like. This should be done in your application side. You should get a list of object relation structure depending on your data access layer( Ado.net, LINQ to SQL , etc..) in the form of *Cateogry->List of Products*. Using linq for example you should do this:

```
var CategoriesWithProducts = Categories.Join(
Products,
c => .Id,
p => p.CategoryId,
(Category, Products) =>
   new
   {
       Category = category,
       ItsProducts = products 
   });

foreach( cateogyr in CategoriesWithProducts)
{
   Console.WriteLine("(List {0})", category.Id);
   Console.WriteLine("Category: {0}", category.Name);
   foreach(var product in category.ItsProducts)
   {
         Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}", product.Name); 
   }
}
```

If you are using ADO.net or any other DAL and there is no way to get these results in a relational way, then you should do this manually, i.e: for each row of data only output the category name and then list their corresponding products.

This is the way you should think of your data representation, always format your data  and how it should look like in your presentation layer of your application, not on the database side.

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson, in your updated query the `m.userid` m is an alias for what, and may be this user has only 1 product for each category try to remove the `where` clause and see the results. It would be ver helpful if you could include a sample data from your table `categories` and `products` and a sample for what do you want the results look like.

Comment: Thanks a lot MGA, I have to go out a bit, but will look into this later this afternoon.